# Validating InitialDirectory for SaveFileDialog?

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, savefiledialog

I'm opening a SaveFileDialog with an initial directory based on a user-defined path. I want make sure this path is valid before passing it in and opening the dialog. Right now I've got this:

```
Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog dialog = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(initialDirectory) && Directory.Exists(initialDirectory))
{
    dialog.InitialDirectory = initialDirectory;
}

bool? result = dialog.ShowDialog();
```

However, it seems `\` is slipping by and causing a crash when I call ShowDialog. Are there other values that could cause crashes? What rules does the InitialDirectory property need to follow?

Comment: Why are you trying to work around a bug?  Fix the bug.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do... but first I need to know HOW to validate the user input before sending it on to the SaveFileDialog.

Comment: SaveFileDialog already does it for you, no point in doing it yourself.  Again, don't hide bugs by avoiding setting the InitialDirectory property.  The exception is *helpful*, it tells you that code is borked and requires your attention.

Comment: The exception is an ArgumentException: "Value does not fall within the expected range.". That's what this question is about. Finding out what the expected "range" is. And it's pretty obvious it's not doing any validation itself, since it just blew up. It's MY job to take the user-input string and pass in something to the SaveFileDialog that doesn't make it throw back an ArgumentException at me. Or are you trying to tell me that I should just catch the ArgumentException?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The quick and easy way to fix it would be to get the full path:

```
dialog.InitialDirectory = Path.GetFullPath(initialDirectory);
```

This will expand relative paths to the absolute ones that the `SaveFileDialog` expects. This will expand just about anything that resembles a path into a full, rooted path. This includes things like "/" (turns into the root of whatever drive the current folder is set to) and "" (turns into the current folder).